# retrieve array from collection

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

The function `getError` populates a collection with arrays of type `variant`. How do I call one of the collection `ErrorValues` items to another function?

It is throwing an error saying Type mismatch: array or user-defined type expected when I call `chartUpdate`.

```
Dim ErrorValues As Collection
Set ErrorValues = getError("80")


Call chartUpdate(1, ErrorValues.Item(1), "Condition 1")
```

`Public Function chartUpdate(chartIdx, cond(), title)`

Answer (score 0):

`Public Function chartUpdate(chartIdx, cond as variant, title)`  I got to work